# Why is LastValidBlockHeight 300 blocks ahead than current BlockHeight if hashes expire in 150?

Tags: web3.js

I am trying to build a correct way to check if a transaction has expired.

Solana Docs state the following: *"By default, RPC nodes will try to forward transactions to leaders every two seconds until either the transaction is finalized or the transaction’s blockhash expires (150 blocks or ~1 minute 19 seconds as of the time of this writing)."* [Source](https://docs.solana.com/integrations/retrying-transactions#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20RPC%20nodes%20will,the%20time%20of%20this%20writing))

The same page also features both: code and verbal examples of how to check for expiry. [Source](https://docs.solana.com/integrations/retrying-transactions#:%7E:text=let%20blockheight%20%3D%20await%20connection.getBlockHeight()%3B%0A%0A%20%20while%20(blockheight%20%3C%20lastValidBlockHeight)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20skipPreflight%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B). The LastValidBlockHeight is 300 blocks ahead of the current BlockHeight. Why? Isn't it supposed to be 150 blocks ahead according to the first source?

```
let blockheight = await connection.getBlockHeight();   
while (blockheight < lastValidBlockHeight) {....
```

There's also another code example [Source](https://docs.solana.com/developing/transaction_confirmation#:%7E:text=Transaction%20has%20expired,currentBankSlot%20%2D%20slotForTxRecentBlockhash%20%3C%20152) for checking expiry which uses Slots instead of Blocks. At this point I am confused If I should use Slots or Blocks and the numbers 300 or 150.

```
Transaction has expired pseudocode: currentBankSlot > slotForTxRecentBlockhash + 151
```

Quicknode Guide also shows something else: [Source](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/transactions/solana-transaction-propagation-handling-dropped-transactions/#:%7E:text=return%20(currentBlockHeight%20%3E%20lastValidBlockHeight%20%2D%20150)%3B)

```
 return (currentBlockHeight > lastValidBlockHeight - 150);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out a blockhash is valid for 150 slots. Therefore you must check if a blockhash is still valid after the transaction is sent to be confident the transaction has landed if you see your signature in a future block.

The following code does just that:

```
  const blockhashResponse = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();
  const lastValidBlockHeight = blockhashResponse.value. lastValidBlockHeight;

  const transaction = new Transaction({
    feePayer: payer.publicKey,
    blockhash: blockhashResponse.value.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: lastValidBlockHeight,
  }).add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      toPubkey: toAccount,
      lamports: 1000000,
    }),
  );
  const message = transaction.serializeMessage();
  const signature = nacl.sign.detached(message, payer.secretKey);
  transaction.addSignature(payer.publicKey, Buffer.from(signature));
  const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
  let blockheight = await connection.getBlockHeight();

  while (blockheight < lastValidBlockHeight) {
    connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
      skipPreflight: true,
    });
    await sleep(500);
    blockheight = await connection.getBlockHeight();
  }
```

The `blockhashResponse` contains the required blockhash + current blockheight related to the blockhash. From there you can add 150 slots to understand how long the blockhash is valid for.

Following that the transaction sent to the cluster until it can no longer be validly sent or retried.

In none of the source provided was anything stated about 300. A blockhash is valid only for 150 slots.

Comment: It seems to me that you are mistakenly using slots and blocks interchangeably. You are calculating `lastValidBlockHeight` by adding 150 to the current `slot` number. current blockheight is much lower number than current slot. `while (blockheight < lastValidBlockHeight)` this is incorrect comparison

According to the following [source](https://docs.solana.com/terminology#skipped-slot) slots might not contain a block ; skipped slots won't bring a blockhash closer to expiry; thus one should use blockHeight-s instead of slots for checking transaction expiry

Comment: Furthermore, the number 300 doesn't come from docs. It comes from the followingRPC response: `connection.getLatestBlockhash()` . The returned value's lastValidBlockHeight
property is always 300 blocks ahead of the current blockHeight. The docs claim that lastValidBlockHeight property is the last block number at which the transaction is still not expired. The docs also claim that the blockhashes expire in 150 blocks, so if they do, My question was why is lastValidBlockHeight 300 blocks ahead of current blockHeight?

Comment: Updated to be consistent. Let me check in on the RPC call, I get your point

Comment: Updated answer to show correct code. I'll update docs as well. The 300 difference is likely just a switched RPC lag.

Comment: This is actually a known weirdness -- `MAX_RECENT_BLOCKHASHES` is 300 https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/e8ea7220618f498a719d2e02ffe0285c8261b513/sdk/program/src/clock.rs#L90 but `MAX_PROCESSING_AGE` is 150 https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/e8ea7220618f498a719d2e02ffe0285c8261b513/sdk/program/src/clock.rs#L98 -- the blockhash queue in the bank tells you 300 + current slot, but it won't be accepted 150 blocks later.